# Can't understand istio authentication policy

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, istio

I'm new to Istio and learning from the official website examples. The one I can't understand is [globally enabling Istio mutual TLS](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/security/authn-policy/#globally-enabling-istio-mutual-tls).

I can run the example with the yaml code present on the web. After that, I changed the `DestinationRule`:

```
kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: "networking.istio.io/v1alpha3"
kind: "DestinationRule"
metadata:
  name: "default"
  namespace: "foo"
spec:
  host: "*.local"
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
      mode: ISTIO_MUTUAL
EOF
```

The only part I changed is replacing the namespace of the example from `istio-system` to `foo`. Then I switch to `foo` namespace, and I run the following test command：

```
$ for from in "foo" "bar"; do for to in "foo" "bar"; do kubectl exec $(kubectl get pod -l app=sleep -n ${from} -o jsonpath={.items..metadata.name}) -c sleep -n ${from} -- curl "http://httpbin.${to}:8000/ip" -s -o /dev/null -w "sleep.${from} to httpbin.${to}: %{http_code}\n"; done; done
```

and the result is below:

```
sleep.foo to httpbin.foo: 503
sleep.foo to httpbin.bar: 200
sleep.bar to httpbin.foo: 503
sleep.bar to httpbin.bar: 503
```

what I expect is:

```
sleep.foo to httpbin.foo: 200
sleep.foo to httpbin.bar: 503
sleep.bar to httpbin.foo: 503
sleep.bar to httpbin.bar: 503
```

Followed the official example, I set a mesh-wide authentication policy that enables mutual TLS, and I then configured the client side mutual TLS on namespace `foo`, I think it should work on namespace `foo`, but it does not work.

Questions:

1. why the status of `sleep.foo to httpbin.foo: 503` is 503 instead of 200?
2. why the status of `sleep.foo to httpbin.bar: 200` is 200 instead of 503?

Is there anyone to explain this? thanks.

Comment: @VadimEisenberg If that is a bug could you please post your comment as an answer? So the other could also see this.

Comment: @leo I have updated the answer: You should wait for 1-2 minutes before the policies will be fully enforced.

Answer (score 1):

You should wait for 1-2 minutes before the policies will be fully enforced.